# What is the purpose of GitHub organization namespaces in Ansible Galaxy for collections

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I noticed in Ansible Galaxy that when I navigate to https://galaxy.ansible.com/my-content/namespaces I see two namespaces:

1. One corresponds with my GitHub username let's say `user`.
2. One corresponds with a GitHub organization I created let's say `mycompany`.

I can build a collection let's say `mycollection` under namespace `user` and `mycompany` but publish only works under `user`. With other words I can only publish `user.mycollection`. If I try to publish `mycompany.mycollection` there is an error message

```sh
user:~/git/ … /ansible-collection-apps] master* ± ansible-galaxy collection publish *.tar.gz --token=2daf0378704a85722dc8a358359f8967b0681917
Publishing collection artifact '/home/user/git/github/mycompany/mycollection/mycollection-1.0.0.tar.gz' to default https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/
ERROR! Error when publishing collection to default (https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/) (HTTP Code: 400, Message: Namespace "mycompany" does not exist. Code: invalid)
```

Clearly I am using Galaxy namespaces created from GitHub organizations such as `mycompany` in an unintended way.

How are these namespaces intended to be used? Can they be used? I tried for example namespace `user.mycompany` but this is not a valid collection namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to request access to additional namespaces. See [Galaxy Namespaces — Ansible Documentation](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/namespaces.html#namespace-limitations)